# dump_bt not working when trying to analyse apache core dumps

Tags: apache, gdb, coredump

I am trying to use dump_bt to analyse an apache core dump as we are getting segmentation faults after moving servers.

The info I got on how to do it is at the following link:

http://www.omh.cc/blog/2008/mar/6/fixing-apache-segmentation-faults-caused-php/

When I run dump_bt I get undefined command, the link I posted also states a conflicting command bt_dump so not sure which is right. Neither works however.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have managed to get the trace working with a red hat php debug library and narrowed it down to a file though not a function. It has given me a line which relates to a custom function for autoloading classes though I can't see what's wrong with that code. I've made a small change so it's now wait and see. We will also be updating php from 5.3.6 to 5.3.8.

Answer (score 2):

You've neglected to do this: "Copy the [.gbdinit](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/.gdbinit) file to your home directory"

It defines `dump_bt` user function.

Comment: I spotted that and using the gdb command "source" you can tell it where your .gdbinit file is without copying it over. It's now telling me "attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a structure".